# Add products to the cart via API from an external script

Tags: javascript, prestashop

My task is to migrate an online WooCommerce store to PrestaShop 8.0.2.

I am working with Visual Studio Code and on a local WampServer.

To accomplish this task, I need to be able to add products to the cart via a simulator using an API generated directly in PrestaShop with all rights.

However, my problem is that when I add a product to the cart, it creates an order in PrestaShop but without the products selected in the simulator.

And according to my browser console, the error would occur during the creation of the cart.

Do you have a solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I am working on an existing project and here is what I have tried:

```
function inputchange(event) {
  var id_input = event.target.id;
  var value_input = event.target.value;
  if (id_input.endsWith("_m")) {
    var value =
      Math.round(((parseFloat(value_input) * 100) / size_dalle) * 100) / 100;
    var input = id_input.substring(0, id_input.length - 2);
    document.getElementById(input).value = value;
  } else {
    var value = (value_input * size_dalle) / 100;
    document.getElementById(id_input + "_m").value = value;
  }
}

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  validate();
});

async function createPrestashopCart() {
  try {
    const response = await $.ajax({
      url: `${prestashopApiBaseUrl}/carts?ws_key=${apiKey}`,
      method: "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: "application/xml; charset=UTF-8",
      data: `<prestashop><cart><id_customer>2</id_customer><id_currency>1</id_currency><id_lang>1</id_lang></cart></prestashop>`,
    });
    if (!response || !response.cart || !response.cart.id) {
      throw new Error("Réponse de l'API invalide lors de la création du panier");
    }
    return response.cart.id;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erreur lors de la création du panier : ", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function addProductToPrestashopCart(cartId, productId, quantity) {
  try {
    const response = await $.ajax({
      url: `${prestashopApiBaseUrl}/carts/${cartId}?ws_key=${apiKey}`,
      method: "PUT",
      processData: false,
      contentType: "application/xml; charset=UTF-8",
      data: `<prestashop><cart><id>${cartId}</id><association><cart_rows><cart_row><id_product>${productId}</id_product><quantity>${quantity}</quantity></cart_row></cart_rows></associations></cart></prestashop>`,
    });
    if (!response || !response.cart) {
      throw new Error("Réponse de l'API invalide lors de l'ajout du produit");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erreur lors de l'ajout du produit au panier : ", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function sendAjaxRequests(cartId, variations, productTable) {
  for (const color in variations) {
    if (productTable[color] !== 0 && color !== "vide" && color !== "Vide") {
      const productId = variations[color];
      await addProductToPrestashopCart(cartId, productId, productTable[color]);
    }
  }
}

async function getCart(cartId) {
  const cartCount = $("#cartCount");
  try {
    const response = await $.ajax({
      url: `${prestashopApiBaseUrl}/carts/${cartId}?ws_key=${apiKey}`,
      method: "GET",
      processData: false,
      contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
    });

    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response,"text/xml");
    const cartRows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('cart_row');
    const itemCount = cartRows.length;

    cartCount.text(itemCount);
    cartCount.css("display", "initial");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    cartCount.text(0);
    cartCount.css("display", "none");
  }
}


addToCart = function (el) {
  const dalleVariations = {
    blanc: 10, //La valeur de droite represente l'ID du produit dans PrestaShop
    bleu: 3,
    "bleu gulf": 4,
    orange: 7,
    jaune: 11,
    rose: 13,
    natural: 12,
    vert: 9,
    "vert clair": 14,
    rouge: 8,
    noir: 6,
    "gris clair": 5,
    beige: 2,
    anthracite: 1,
   };


  const bordureVariations = {
    "bordure anthracite": 18,
    "bordure beige": 16,
    "bordure gris clair": 19,
    "bordure noir": 15,
    "bordure rouge": 17,
    "angle anthracite": 20,
    "angle beige": 21,
    "angle gris clair": 24,
    "angle noir": 22,
    "angle rouge": 23
  };

  const addButton = $("#addToCart");
  const addButton2 = $("#addToCart2");
  const successMessage = $("#successMessage");
  const successMessage2 = $("#successMessage2");
  addButton.text("Ajout en cours...");
  addButton2.text("Ajout en cours...");

  (async function () {
    try {
      const cartId = await createPrestashopCart();

      await sendAjaxRequests(cartId, dalleVariations, tab);
      await sendAjaxRequests(cartId, bordureVariations, tabBordure);
      await getCart();
      addButton.text("Ajouter au panier");
      successMessage.text("Le produit a été ajouté au panier");
      successMessage.css("color", "green");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      addButton.text("Erreur...");
      successMessage.text(
        "Une erreur est survenue, déconnectez-vous ou contactez contact@easy-dalles.fr !"
      );
      successMessage2.text(
        "Une erreur est survenue, déconnectez-vous ou contactez contact@easy-dalles.fr !"
      );
      successMessage.css("color", "red");
      successMessage2.css("color", "red");
    }
  })();
};
```

Error:

> GET http://localhost/easy-dalles2/api/carts/undefined?ws_key=MRR8V4IAF1TVFF5QF1AGKZMLNLNUTG7F 404 (Not Found)

```
- send @ jquery.min.js:4
- ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
- getCart @ inputManagement.js:72
- (anonyme) @ script.js:36
inputManagement.js:82 {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}abort: ƒ (a)always: ƒ ()catch: ƒ (a)done: ƒ ()fail: ƒ ()getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)pipe: ƒ ()progress: ƒ ()promise: ƒ (a)readyState: 4responseText: ""setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)state: ƒ ()status: 404statusCode: ƒ (a)statusText: "Not Found"then: ƒ (b,d,e)[[Prototype]]: Object
getCart @ inputManagement.js:82
await in getCart (asynchrone)
(anonyme) @ script.js:36
www-embed-player.js:927
```

> inputManagement.js:37 Erreur lors de la création du panier :  Error: Réponse de l'API invalide lors de la création du panier

```
- at createPrestashopCart (inputManagement.js:33:13)
- at async inputManagement.js:130:22
- createPrestashopCart @ inputManagement.js:37
- await in createPrestashopCart (asynchrone)
- (anonyme) @ inputManagement.js:130
- addToCart @ inputManagement.js:150
- onclick @ VM857 :1
```

> inputManagement.js:139 Error: Réponse de l'API invalide lors de la création du panier

```
- at createPrestashopCart (inputManagement.js:33:13)
- at async inputManagement.js:130:22
```

Comment: Please post the error message and create a [mcve]

Comment: I have posted 2 photos of the errors displayed in my browser's console.

Comment: It's done, I did the best I could, sorry in advance

Comment: I've removed the none-related errors. Furthermore, have a look at the first error: "*GET http://localhost/easy-dalles2/api/carts/undefined*". That URL is definitely incorrect. Verify how you are building this URL, because you are concatenating an *undefined* variable. - Seems `${cartId}` is undefined: `url: '${prestashopApiBaseUrl}/carts/${cartId}?ws_key=${apiKey}'`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the modification and I'm still getting the same errors. I think the problem comes from somewhere else. I will continue my research on my side.